# Using applescript within VBA to use safari

Tags: excel, vba, macos, applescript, automator

I was trying to run a VBA Excel Macro on my mac that sends commands to other apps (explorer).

I figured this doesn't work on the mac, and found that applescript is a bypass solution, but I don't have a clue on how to create one or even call it from excel, so here it goes: I have an excel file with data and the macro opens an website on IE, inputs this data on a certain point, then go back to the excel file and puts an ok beside the data telling that it was done (looks simple).

How do I do this using applescript? In short, I need it to gather some info on the excel file, then input this data on an specific field of a webpage (and click ok) and then go back to excel and there I think I could go back to using VBA again until another loop.